# Как исправить ошибку в двумерном массиве с динамическим выделением памяти?

Tags: массивы, память, c

Выдает ошибку: "Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x010D1753 в ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000".

Что она означает и как ее исправить?

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include"conio.h"
#include"locale.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"time.h"

// Функция генерации случайных чисел в диапазоне от range_min до range_max
int rnd(int range_min, int range_max)
{
    return (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1) * (range_max - range_min) + range_min;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    int **a;
    int i, min, j, sum, n, m, V, l, k;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    printf("Введите размерность массива: \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    a = (int**)calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 1; i <= n + 1; i++)
        a[i] = (int*)calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int));
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            a[i][j] = rnd (-5, 5);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    //____________________________________________________________________________________________

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        min = 0;
        if (a[0][j] < a[0][j + 1] && a[0][j] < a[0][j - 1] && a[0][j] < a[1][j])
        {
            i = 0;
            printf("\n %d %d", i, j);
            min = min + 1;

        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (a[n - 1][j] < a[n - 1][j - 1] && a[n - 1][j] < a[n - 1][j + 1] && a[n - 1][j] < a[n - 2][j])
        {
            i = n - 1;
            printf("\n %d %d", i, j);
            min = min + 1;

        }
    }
    //____________________________________________________________________________________________

    for (i = 1; i<n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] < a[i][j - 1] && a[i][j] < a[i][j + 1] && a[i][j] < a[i - 1][j] && a[i][j] < a[i + 1][j])
            {
                printf("\n %d %d", i, j);
                min = min + 1;

            }
        }
    }

    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j<n; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                l = 10 - j;
                for (j = i; j < l; j++)
                {
                    sum = sum + abs(a[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n Количество локальных минимумов заданной матрицы равно: %d  ", min);
    printf("\n Сумма модулей элементов выше главной диагонали равна: %d  ", sum);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: @Ред, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Эта ошибка означает, что Вы пытаетесь читать данные из переменной, указывающей в NULL (или имеющей значение 0, что в С одно и то же).

Исправить это можно - если не читать память из переменной, указывающей в NULL. Где именно в Вашей простыне то самое место сказать очень трудно, поскольку простыня большая. А создавать проект и тестировать это у себя, потому что Вы поленились локализовать область когда, где это происходит, мне лень.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка у Вас в том, что Вы то берете индексы от 1, то от 0.

Например, в самом начале:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n + 1; i++)
    a[i] = (int*)calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int));
```

Обратите внимание `a[0]` останется 0 (оно же NULL), и чуть дальше:

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    min = 0;
    if (a[0][j] < a[0][j + 1] && a[0][j] < a[0][j - 1] && a[0][j] < a[1][j])
    {
```

Вы обращаетесь к `a[0]`.

В Си принято использовать индексы с 0.

Поэтому исправьте:

```
a = (int**)calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int*));
for (i = 1; i <= n + 1; i++)
    a[i] = (int*)calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int));
```

на

```
a = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a[i] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

и т.д.